# Sliding captions not working

Tags: html, css

Im using a pure css sliding caption for one of my pages. The intention is for the whole caption to slide out from the right to left when the image is hovered over.

However, it doesnt seem to be working. I based my code on http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-image-captions/ ,so that the fullwidth image will have a caption. It is the "programmesimages" and "programmesimagescaption" classes.

```css
    * {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
body{
 background: url(../images/subtle_white_mini_waves.png) repeat;
}
#wrapper{
 width:1180px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
#programmescontent{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:1000px;
 background:#333;
 z-index:-50;
 margin-top:-73px;
}
.programmesimages{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:600px; 
 background:#fff;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.programmesimages img{
 position: absolute;  
    left: 0;  
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
}
.programmesimagescaption{
 background-color:#CF0;  
    position: absolute;  
    color: #fff;  
    z-index: 100;  
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
 width:1180px;
 height:600px;
 left:1180px;
}
.programmesimages:hover .programmesimagescaption{
 -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);  
   -o-transform: translateX(-100%);  
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);  
   opacity: 1;  
   transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.programmesimages:hover img{
 -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);  
  -o-transform: translateX(-100%);  
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);  
   transform: translateX(-100%);  
}
```

```html
  
  <div id="programmescontent">
    <div class="programmesimages">
         <img src="http://www.thevisibilityproject.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/TheEndAgain_288-1180x600.jpg">
            <div class="programmesimagescaption">
             <h3>Caption</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="programmescarousel">
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for using the Code snippet button, but could you narrow it down to minimal example that still has the issue. That will be much easier to debug, both for us and for you. Currently it seems to be an entire page with all its CSS and most of it is just noise to the problem.

Comment: Yep, I have done that!

Comment: Oh hey, nevermind, thanks, Ive fixed the issue. It was a really messed up Z-index problem that forced every single element on all my pages down so nothing could be "hovered"